# C++: dynamically allocating a member array of structs using non-default constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, struct, memory-management

If I have:

```
struct a_struct
{
    int an_int;

    a_struct(int f) : an_int(f) {}
    a_struct() : an_int(0) {}
};

class a_class
{
    a_struct * my_structs;

    a_class() {...}
};
```

I can do:

```
a_class() {my_structs = new a_struct(1)}
//or  
a_class() {my_structs = new a_struct [10]}
```

But I *cannot* do:

```
a_class() {my_structs = new a_struct(1) [10]}
//or
a_class() {my_structs = new a_struct() [10]}
```

Is there any correct syntax to get this to work? Or an easy work around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using the STL is an option, you could use std::vector instead of a dynamic array.

I *think* that this will work:

```
std::vector<a_struct> my_structs;

my_structs.assign(10, 1);
```

If not, this should:

```
my_structs.assign(10, a_struct(1));
```

Comment: Or just `std::vector<a_struct> my_structs(10, 1);`

Answer (score 4):

You could allocate a raw chunk of memory and use **placement new** to initialize each `struct`:

```
int number_of_structs = 10;
my_structs = (a_struct*)new unsigned char[sizeof(a_struct) * number_of_structs];
     // allocate a raw chunk of memory 
a_struct* p = m_structs;
for (int i=0; i<number_of_structs; i++)
{
    new (p) a_struct(i);
    p++;
}

//When done should add code for deallocation to help people 
// to understand the full cycle of memory management.  
for (auto i=0; i<number_of_structs; ++i) {
    my_structs[i].~a_struct(); 
} 
delete[] my_structs;
```

See also: [What uses are there for "placement new"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new)

Comment: For modern C++ casting syntax (a_struct*) might be replaced with reinterpret_cast or static_cast?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of pointers to pointers. Then you can create the array that will hold pointers to a_struct(), so you can decide later which constructor to use:

```
class a_class {
    a_struct ** my_structs;

    a_class() { my_structs = new a_struct* [10]}
    void foo () {
       my_structs[0] = new a_struct(1);
       my_structs[5] = new a_struct("some string and float constructor", 3.14);
    }
};
```

Comment: This does not allow you to pass around an array of structs (or pointer to the struct then  use pointer math to move to the next element of the array).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly on any particular parameterized constructor. However you can do,

```
a_struct *my_struct[10] = {}; // create an array of pointers

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    my_struct[i] = new a_struct(i); // allocate using non-default constructor
```

I suggest using a `std::vector` container instead of going through this process.

Comment: The advantage of `std::vector` in this case is that all `my_struct`s will be in a contiguous memory block.

Comment: This does not allow you to pass around an array of structs (or pointer to the struct then use pointer math to move to the next element of the array)